# How to use regex to replace a string of symbols

Tags: regex

I am using `regex` in `VsCode` to replace the symbol `*` by the symbol `#` in the following situation:

```
* one
** two
*** three
```

by

```
# one
## two
### three
```

I was using `[*]` and `[\*]{3}\s` without coming to a solution.

Comment: What is the criterion to match these `#`s? Because  they are followed with a space?

Comment: I want to match those *. Yes they are all followed by a space.

Comment: Sorry, I am without glasses :) Try `\*(?=\**\s)` and replace with `#`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but when I replace it results in spaces between the symbols like `# #` and `# # #`. But I think this is a replace question and not a regex question.

Comment: See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/r9A5Ba/1). It should work if your requirement is like the one I mentioned: any `*` that is followed with 0+ `s` and then a whitespace.

Comment: OK the demo works fine. So I think this replace problem has to do with `VsCode`. I will try it with other text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

*Find What*: `\*(?=\**\s)`
*Replace With*: `#`

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/r9A5Ba/1).

**Details**

- `\*` - a `*` char
- `(?=\**\s)` - a positive lookahead that requres 0 or more `*` chars followed with a whitespace immediately to the right of the current location.

See the VSCode demo:

[image]

After clicking *Replace all*:

[image]

Comment: The problem with the space had to do with the fact that I had the `Preserve case` selected :-(.